# What type of FLASH (NAND or NOR) is used on microcontoller?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, flash-memories, nand-flash

I am doing a study on file systems for mcirocontollers (MCU), using internal flash only. I find my self asking this questions: What type of FLASH memory is used most commonly in MCU ? NAND or NOR?

This can be useful to know when designing or selecting a file system.

I have been looking at datasheet from various MCU (STM32, MSP430, Atmel), but I was not able to find this information. They just says "FLASH memory". Anybody know what is generally used ?

(I know that some use FRAM, but I asking only about FLASH memory technology)

Comment: Flash refers to the fact that it is written to in chunks. This makes deleting/writing faster. I don't know if this still applies tho. Most use floating-gate technology, if memory serves me right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET I don't know from heart if nand or nor is better, but I know one is gennerally superior in terms of lifecycles.

Comment: Usually, microcontrollers can execute code from their internal flash, this is NOR flash because it allows random accesses, whereas NAND is block-only. This code FLASH may not be partially eraseable, or very limited in the number of write/erase cycles. Some microcontrollers have several types of nonvolatile memory, some have EEPROM cells (where each byte can be individually rewritten). This really depends on the chip.

Comment: Can be inferred from the datasheet by seeing whether it's byte-erasable or block-erasable. Not all MCUs actually let you overwrite the flash from inside at all.

Comment: @pjc50: Then if the datasheet say its' block-erasable (which is the case for all datasheet I have been looking at), then the Flash is ..... ?

Comment: Block-erasable implies NAND.

Comment: @pjc50 Doesn't byte-erasable imply EEPROM, and not flash at all?  Both NAND and NOR are block-erasable.  Did you mean byte-readable by chance?

Answer (score 4):

Undoubtly, for program memory, the memory of choice is NOR Flash. NAND flash has several issues that make it unsuitable for program storage (NAND has to be accessed in blocks and has the bad habit of corrupting some of its data, so a management system is needed to keep track of blocks usage and of bad records. You don't want to put your program on an unreliable media).

Comment: Are you sure? NAND has to be *written* in blocks, but can be randomly read, and once successfully written tends to stay there. Program memory in production units is usually only ever written a small number of times.

Comment: NAND and NOR are equally realiable *at the same density*. However, NAND is easiler to scale down.

Comment: @pjc50 - yes I am sure, one of the most important difference between NOR and NAND is that NOR is random-accessable while NAND isn't

Comment: @CL - not at all, NOR flash memories DO NOT need a bad sector manager, while NAND memories DO.

Comment: I can write Kinetis flash word at a time (4 bytes), so I would guess that it uses NOR.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami Are you talking about NOR and NAND flash memories *with the same density*?

Comment: I second Claudio Avi Chami. Given the same technological node, NAND flash are less reliable than NOR. That's because the main purpose of NAND flash is not reliability. It's to store as much information as you can. The tunnel oxide is typically smaller, and that's a big issue in terms of reliability: a single defect can discharge the whole floating gate.

Comment: Here is a description about NOR and NAND from the documentation of [**OpenOCD**](http://openocd.org/doc-release/html/Flash-Commands.html#norconfiguration):
*"**NOR** flash usually supports direct CPU instruction and data bus access, while data from a **NAND** flash must be copied to memory before it can be used."*

So it should be **NOR**.